# How to properly use git with local remote

Tags: git, github, version-control

TLDR:
I set-up a local remote but it seems to work for pushing and pulling but not very well for syncing..

---

Here are the details.

I learn a little about working with remote.

So I want to use git locally both for my working directory but also as my remote repo (in place of a service like Github).

For this I first initialized my first (working) project repo :

```
#[~/project/project_ABC] → git init
```

After some work on it I add and commit all my work so I end up with a clean working directory repo.

But instead of pushing this work on a web remote service (like Github) I wanted to actually **host** the remote locally.

So I *bare* initialize a repo on a dedicated folder *(paying attention to name it with the .git suffix)* :

```
#[~/repos/project_ABC.git] → git init --bare
```

Then, coming back to my working directory, I push my work to this "*remote*" repo after adding it to my list of remote repo :

```
#[~/project/project_ABC] → git remote add local ~/repos/project_ABC.git
#[~/project/project_ABC] → git push local master
```

At this time when I `git status -uno` I get that everything is good...

To test that this "*remote*" repo is actually working I made some change to my work in my working directory and commit them (in the working directory).

So at this time if I `git status -uno` I get that my `branch is ahead of 'local/master' by 1 commit.`
Yay..Pushing to that repo seems working..
So I `git push` my work and everything is good.

But I also wanted to try that pulling from this repo works too..
So I git clone from this *local "remote"* repo to another working directory and made some changes (and in this case the remote is named `origin` as it should be:

```
#[~/test] → git clone ~/repos/project_ABC
   ... made some changes, committing and then pushing to remote
#[~/test/project_ABC] → git push origin master
```

Here is the fancy part!
Back to my original working directory I expect that when I `git status -uno` to get the message that my `branch is behind of "local/master" by 1 commit.`

But nope!
I get the message that my `branch is up-to-date with local/master.`

So what's going on here ?

Thank you in advance.
*And sorry for my bad  english..*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on here is that `git status` only shows the information it actually knows, which is a comparison of your local branch against its local *tracking* branch which tracks the actual remote branch.  When you pushed a commit to the local repo from the second clone, Git did not know about this because the tracking branch was not synched.

To get around this, you should make the habit of doing a `git fetch` before you do `git status`.  So if, from your original working directory, you had done the following:

```
git fetch origin master
git status
```

then I expect you would have seen:

```
branch is behind of "local/master" by 1 commit
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer..

I did as you said, and indeed with the `fetch` command it works..

In fact I understand that in a regular workflow, syncing with the remote is not something we did at every commit..

Also, I changed my prompt (with much difficulties) in order to track the status against the remote.. I would like that I can get if my working directory is behind or ahead of the remote without running the `fetch` command...

It seems that this is not possible...

Comment: @SanjiBukai You could create a custom Git command which does a fetch followed by a `git status`, which would ensure that you always are looking at the most up to date information.  To counter your concern, there are instances where you would _not_ want the local tracking branch to be synched up with the remote.